# Нужно ли согласование падежа при указании фамилии в скобках

Tags: орфография

"получено положительное заключение Минфина России (И.И.Иванов)"

Comment: @ЕНН, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Жёсткого правила здесь нет. Скобки на то и скобки, чтобы иметь обособленную форму. Определяющим будет ваше собственное представление о том, как лучше звучит и выглядит.